# Python | Skipping a user_input

Tags: python, user-input

I have a problem with my python script as when this question comes up:

```
("Is there problem with the software or hardware? ")
```

When I type in "Software" my first software question comes up

```
("Is your phone freezing/stuttering? ")
```

So if I answer yes a solution comes up b``ut if I type in No then my hardware question comes up but I dont want that to happen.

Here is my script:

```
phone2 = input("Is there problem with the software or hardware? ") #Question
if phone2 == "Software" or phone2 == "software" :
def foo():
 while True:
  return False
s1 = input("Is your phone freezing/stuttering? ")
if s1 == "Yes" or s1 == "yes" :
  print("Try deleting some apps and this might help with your problem")
if s1 == "No" or s1 == "no" :
  def foo():
   while True:
      return False
if phone2 == "Hardware" or phone2 == "hardware" :
    def foo():
     while True:
      return False
h1 = input("Does your phone switch on? ")
if h1 == "No" or h1 == "no" :
    print("There might be a issue with your battery. I recommend replacing          it with the help of a specialist")
if h1 == "Yes" or h1 == "yes" :
    def foo():
     while True:
        return False
```

Comment: `def foo(): while True: return False` What do you think this does?

Comment: use `if.....elif` instead of two `if...if`, or even `if...else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that you did not use proper indentations after your `if` statements ,hence the rest of your code was executed anyway:

```
phone2 = input("Is there problem with the software or hardware? ") #Question
if phone2 == "Software" or phone2 == "software" :
    def foo():
        while True:
             return False
    s1 = input("Is your phone freezing/stuttering? ")
    if s1 == "Yes" or s1 == "yes":
        print("Try deleting some apps and this might help with your problem")
    if s1 == "No" or s1 == "no":
        def foo():
            while True:
                return False
if phone2 == "Hardware" or phone2 == "hardware":
    def foo():
        while True:
            return False
    h1 = input("Does your phone switch on? ")
    if h1 == "No" or h1 == "no":
        print("There might be a issue with your battery. I recommend replacing it with the help of a specialist")
    if h1 == "Yes" or h1 == "yes":
        def foo():
            while True:
                return False
```

PS: (I don't think you need that "foo" function in there.)

Answer (score 7):

(1) Think about what if clauses do.

(2) Make sure you understand what tabs/spaces do in python.

Here is how to do it:

```
phone2 = input("Is there problem with the software or hardware? ") 
if phone2 == "Software" or phone2 == "software":
    s1 = input("Is your phone freezing/stuttering? ")
    if s1 == "Yes" or s1 == "yes" :
       print("Try deleting some apps and this might help with your problem")
if phone2 == "Hardware" or phone2 == "hardware" :
   h1 = input("Does your phone switch on? ")
   if h1 == "No" or h1 == "no" :
      print("There might be a issue with your battery.")
```