# Python | Stopping/Restarting a script after user_input

Tags: python, if-statement, user-input

Just before I ask the question I would like to say that I am very new to Python so what ever I ask might be simple to do.

My question is this: How do I stop the script after this question has been answered.

```
s1 = input("Is your phone freezing/stuttering? ")
if s1 == "Yes" or s1 == "yes":
    print("Try deleting some apps and this might help with your problem")
if s1 == "No" or s1 == "no":
    def foo():
        while True:
            return False
```

So what I exactly want here is when the user replies with 'Yes' I want the solution to come up and the script to stop or if possible even restart.

Comment: What do you think `def foo()` does? I wanted to know what you think so I can clarify it you that it doesn't do what you are thinking.

Comment: `def foo()` is useless - you define function but you don't use it (you don't execute it). `while True: return False` does the same as simple `return False`

Answer (score 0):

A simple exit could be reach by this.

I also used the lower function so it will look a bit more pythonic

With just a simple loop:

```
s1 = "yes"
while s1 == "yes":
  s1 = input("Is your phone freezing/stuttering? ").lower()
```

Good luck !

Comment: @furas Is this the same questioner. You and me answered a question like this before I guess.

Comment: @furas I've added a solution with just a simple loop as well

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi I see this question first time but OP has similar question in his profile http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144688/python-skipping-a-user-input

Comment: @furas Oh my bad. It was this one I was talking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176910/python-programming-decision-structures/41176944#41176944

Answer (score -3):

What you could do is create a loop around it

```
x = 4
while x == 4:
    s1 = input("Is your phone freezing/stuttering? ")
    if s1 == "Yes" or s1 == "yes":
        print("Try deleting some apps and this might help with your problem")
    if s1 == "No" or s1 == "no":
        def foo():
            while True:
                return False
        break #<-- only if you want the program to end after false#
```

Comment: why `x == 4` ? `while True` will do the same

Comment: foo is never called.