# Python | IF statment stop script after user input has been made

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I am currently working on a automated troubleshooter using Python. Below is a piece of my script which I need help with.

```
s1 = input("Is your phone freezing/stuttering? ")
if s1 == "Yes" or s1 == "yes":
    print("Try deleting some apps and this might help with your problem.") 
if s1 == "No" or s1 == "no":
    def foo():
        while True:
            return False
```

So what I want to happen is my script to stop when the user types in YES and when the solution to the fix comes up. Is there a possible loop for that or something similar? Also if the user types in NO then I want the script to continue to the next question.

Comment: is this in a function? `return`?

Comment: Immediately returning in a loop is pointless and generally, never define a function in an if statement. Your question is unclear though... What are you trying to loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python | Stopping/Restarting a script after user\_input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264055/python-stopping-restarting-a-script-after-user-input)

Comment: And please do not repost

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what do you want? Your question seems to be unclear.

Comment: Basically I want the script to stop after I type in 'yes'

Comment: is this all your code?

Comment: You can stop a script at any point by calling `sys.exit()`.

Comment: The rest of my code is just a repeat of what I posted here but its just a different question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So one thing that you can do is utilize the `sys`.

So you can modify your program to look like the following:

```
import sys

s1 = input("Is your phone freezing or stuttering (yes/no)? ")

if s1.lower() == "yes":
    print("Deleting some apps and this might help!")

elif s1.lower() == "no":
    print("Your phone is working fine! Program is terminating.")
    sys.exit(0) # this exits your program with exit code 0
```

The `sys` package is great for program control and also interacting with the interpreter. Please read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html).

If you don't want your program to exit and you just want to check that the user entered no, you could do something like:
    import sys

```
s1 = input("Is your phone freezing or stuttering (yes/no)? ")

if s1.lower() == "yes":
    print("Deleting some apps and this might help!")

elif s1.lower() == "no":
    pass

else:
    # if the user printed anything else besides yes or no
    print("Your phone is working fine! Program is terminating.")
    sys.exit(0) # this exits your program with exit code 0
```

Let me know if I can help in any other way!

#### EDIT

A comment by crickt_007 suggested that it might be helpful to repeat the input and continually query the user. You could wrap this whole function in a while loop then.

```
import sys

while True:
    s1 = input("Is your phone freezing or stuttering (yes/no)? ")

    if s1.lower() == "yes":
        print("Deleting some apps and this might help!")
        # solve their issue

    elif s1.lower() == "no":
        # supposedly move on to the rest of the problem
        pass

    else:
        # if the user printed anything else besides yes or no
        # maybe we want to just boot out of the program
        print("An answer that is not yes or no has been specified. Program is terminating.")
        sys.exit(0) # this exits your program with exit code 0
```

Comment: I would repeat the input if not yes/no

Comment: @cricket_007 Probably a good call! Let me change my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

A while loop sounds like what you are looking for?

```
import sys

s1 = "no"
while s1.lower() != 'yes':
    input("Is your phone freezing/stuttering? ")
    if s1.lower() == 'yes':
        print("Try deleting some apps and this might help with your problem.")
        sys.exit(0)
    elif s1.lower() == 'no':
        print("something")
    else:
        print("invalid input")
```